# get element text from destination page instead of current page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, google-analytics

I have this script for my dynamic content which seems to be doing the trick. I have to do it this way because I cannot access the code-behind in the asp.net project. The only problem is that I want to try and fetch the ("div.sampleheading").text() from the NEXT loaded page, and not the current page. This is what I have in my master page:

```
function readyFn( jQuery ) {
if ($('div.sampleheading').length) {
function sendit() {
ga('create', 'UA-******', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview', url + $("div.sampleheading").text());
 }

var el = document.body;
el.addEventListener("click", sendit, false);
}
else
{
ga('create', 'UA-******', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
}
}
$( window ).load( readyFn );
</script>
```

Basically, i send the URL and the text from sampleheading to analytics, but the url is the new page, and the sampleheading.text is the previous page heading.  Is there a way I can make jquery execute when the NEW page is loaded?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Until and Unless the next page is loaded via AJAX you cannot get the text
So you need to change content via ajax and then send the pageview